# How to read JsonArray in Java (gson)

Tags: java, json, gson

I get the following Json response

> [{"symbol":"ETHBTC","bidPrice":"0.09086600","bidQty":"10.96000000","askPrice":"0.09095200","askQty":"43.49600000"},{
>   ....

With a com.google.gson.JsonArray.  What I have done so far:

```
JsonArray askbid = new BinanceApi().allBookTickers();

for (JsonElement obj : askbid)
{
    JsonObject jobj = obj.getAsJsonObject();
    ???
}
```

I don't know how to continue. There is no option to get the parameters I need. How can I proceed ?

Comment: `jobj.get('bidPrice').getAsBigDecimal()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
 JsonArray askbid = new BinanceApi().allBookTickers();

 for (JsonElement obj : askbid)
 {
         JsonObject jobj = obj.getAsJsonObject();
         String symbol = jobj.get("symbol").toString();
         String bidPrice = jobj.get("bidPrice").toString();
         String bidQty = jobj.get("bidQty").toString();
         String askPrice = jobj.get("askPrice").toString();
         String askQty = jobj.get("askQty").toString();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fromJSON` method of GSON and pass `CryptoDTO[].class` as method parameter to convert JSON into ArrayList of your DTO.

```
    public CryptoDTO[] convertJsonToList(String json){
     GSON gson=new GSON();
     return gson.fromJson(json, CryptoDTO[].class);
 }
```

Comment: `CryptoDTO` sounds like something you use, but isn't related to the question, and liable to just confuse someone new to this subject...

Comment: It's added after watching content in the JSON data. And I don't find it confusing bcoz it's just a name of class

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaDocs for Gson](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) are pretty clear about what getter methods exist on `JsonObject` class:

> ```
> JsonElement   get(String memberName) // Returns the member with the specified name.
> JsonArray     getAsJsonArray(String memberName) // Convenience method to get the specified member as a JsonArray.
> JsonObject    getAsJsonObject(String memberName) // Convenience method to get the specified member as a JsonObject.
> JsonPrimitive getAsJsonPrimitive(String memberName) // Convenience method to get the specified member as a JsonPrimitive element.
> ```